How can I draw another secondary Y axis to a chart same as Pareto
I'm trying to draw secondary Y axis to a chart same as what they called Pareto chart
The expected chart
I can't find a way to figure it out. I have tried to search on the documentation and on demo examples on the gihub repo, but haven't found any help
but keep showing as the following
My current chart
Any help or hint would be appreciated
this is my code
   $dataSeriesLabels = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'ErrorFrequency!$C$1', null, 1),
    ];
    $xAxisTickValues = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'ErrorFrequency!$B$2:$B$'.($this->rowIndex-1), null, $totalRowsCount),

    ];
    $dataSeriesValues = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'ErrorFrequency!$C$2:$C$'.($this->rowIndex-1), null, $totalRowsCount),
    ];
    $series = new DataSeries(
        DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,
        DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,
        range(0, count($dataSeriesValues) - 1),
        $dataSeriesLabels,
        $xAxisTickValues,
        $dataSeriesValues
    );

    // second axis
    $dataSeriesLabels2 = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'ErrorFrequency!$E$1', null, 1),
    ];
    $dataSeriesValues2 = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'ErrorFrequency!$E$2:$E$'.($this->rowIndex-1), null, $totalRowsCount),
    ];
    
    // Build the dataseries
    $series2 = new DataSeries(
        DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,
        DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD ,
        range(0, count($dataSeriesValues2) - 1),
        $dataSeriesLabels2,
        [],
        $dataSeriesValues2
    );

           $series2->setPlotDirection(DataSeries::DIRECTION_VERTICAL);


    $plotArea = new PlotArea(null, [$series,$series2]);
    $legend = new Legend(Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);

    $title = new Title('Pareto Chart - Error Types (20% of errors cause 80% of issues)');
    $yAxisLabel = new Title('Error Counts');
    $secondaryYAxisLabel = new Title('Secondary Axis Label');  




    $yaxis = new Axis();
    $xaxis = new Axis();
    $yaxis->setAxisOptionsProperties('low', null, null, null, null, null, -20, 20, null, null);
    
    $xaxis->setAxisOptionsProperties('low', null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null, null);

    // Create the chart
    $chart = new Chart(
        'chart',
        $title,
        $legend,
        $plotArea,
        true,
        DataSeries::EMPTY_AS_GAP,
        null, // xAxisLabel
        $yAxisLabel,  // yAxisLabel
        null, // xAxis
        null,  // yAxis
        null,  // majorGridlines
        null,  //minor Gridlines
        $secondaryYAxisLabel  
    );
    $chart->setTopLeftPosition('I3');
    $chart->setBottomRightPosition('Z25');
    $worksheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $worksheet->addChart($chart);


Well it seems that the secondary axis is not supported yet !
So I have to do a workaround to solve it

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
